# How to change the 'Registry' value which shows from 'docker info'

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-machine

When I run `docker info`, it shows such information:

```
~ $ docker info
Containers: 0
Images: 8
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 9
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.1.13-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.9.1 (TCL 6.4.1); master : cef800b - Fri Nov 20 19:33:59 UTC 2015
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.956 GiB
Name: default
ID: CXQT:PB43:QNMD:W5JY:66QM:QRI7:GJUB:X27R:RQ4U:53I2:QVJS:DYKV
Debug mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 17
 Goroutines: 29
 System Time: 2015-12-15T06:26:35.824197223Z
 EventsListeners: 1
 Init SHA1:
 Init Path: /usr/local/bin/docker
 Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Username: freewind
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
```

You can notice at the bottom there is a `Registry`:

```
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

I want to know to change this value, say, to change it to `http://localhost:5000`, so it will always pull images from `http://localhost:5000`?

---

PS: I already tried to add `--engine-registry-mirror http://localhost:5000` when creating a docker machine:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox \
    --engine-registry-mirror http://localhost:5000 default
```

And in the `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` of the machine, it contains the content:

```
EXTRA_ARGS='
--label provider=virtualbox
--registry-mirror http://localhost:5000

'
```

In order to ask it to pull images from `http://localhost:5000` first. But I still wonder how to change the global `Registry` value (shows in `docker info`)

Answer (score 1):

> how to change the global Registry value (shows in docker info)

This seems fixed in [`registry/config.go#L30-L31`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/75d69ce0da2e360773736502acd92d4a9cf7faa5/registry/config.go#L30-L31)

```
// IndexServer is the v1 registry server used for user auth + account creation
    IndexServer = DefaultV1Registry + "/v1/"
```

Note that the registry service [will first look for v2 endpoint anyway](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/75d69ce0da2e360773736502acd92d4a9cf7faa5/registry/service.go#L174-L175).

```
func (s *Service) lookupEndpoints(repoName reference.Named) (endpoints []APIEndpoint, err error) {
    endpoints, err = s.lookupV2Endpoints(repoName)
```

[Issue 16974](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16974) asks "why not make mirror support a private v2 registry until now?"

> Without going into detail, the main issue here is trust and provenance. Basically, the registry controls the naming, so once you point the daemon at another registry, you can no longer trust the content if layers collide. We avoid these issues by disallowing arbitrary mirroring.
>
> This is a situation we are working on resolving but it will take some effort to appropriately address.

More specifically, this is followed in [distribution PR 1136](https://github.com/docker/distribution/pull/1136), with [Proxying to other Registries](https://github.com/RichardScothern/distribution/blob/183d1445203798a9c01ac4b292285a0d9ef8fd35/ROADMAP.md#proxying-to-other-registries):

> A pull-through caching mode exists for the registry, but **is restricted from within the docker client to only mirror the official Docker Hub**.
> This functionality can be expanded when image provenance has been specified and implemented in the distribution project.

For now, all you can do is to add `--disable-legacy-registry` to make sure to consider only V2 ones. That won't change the `docker info` output though.

Comment: thanks, I tried to add `--disable-legacy-registry`, but it reports this flag is not supported. My docker version is `Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5`, is it added in very recent docker codebase?

Comment: @Freewind It is an option of the docker daemon CLI: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/. So it is supported in docker 1.9.1.